# How to generate xsd from xml in code behind

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

What I want to do is generating `xsd` `file` from `xml` which will be passed as `string`.

Sample:
Let's say we have that kind of `xml` passed in `string`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Sample>
      <SampleId>41111111124</AnimalId>
      <SampleName>string</SampleKind>
   </Sample>
```

I would like to generate from this above `xsd` `file` from code behind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xs:element name="Sample">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="SampleId" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
               <xs:element name="SampleName" type="xs:string" />
             </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

On msdn couldn't find such thing.

**Is it even possible to make it in `c#` code behind?**

Comment: You can include in your project xsd.exe

Comment: Well I found exactly what asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found solution for this:
[XmlSchemaInference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemainference.aspx) is what I needed.